# Python requests - make chain of requests

Tags: python, python-requests

When a browser makes, say, a GET request, it downloads a bunch of data regarding what other requests it needs to make. Then it sends those requests automatically.

From my understanding, the python requests module just makes the one request, unless it is redirected.

Is it possible to have Requests make the entire chain of HTTP requests?

Comment: so you mean, download the HTML, parse the <script> tag, evaluate javascript within some engin, and execute only those functions which make external http requests?.. HUMMMMMM

Comment: Making requests for everything that's just in the DOM would be sufficient.

Comment: What is the goal here? Is it to profile all network requests in the DOM? Trying to do so with Request is really stretching what it is intended to do, if that is your goal try looking at something like PythonWebkit - https://www.gnu.org/software/pythonwebkit/

Comment: I am building a load tester with locust.io, ideally it should legitimately stress test a page by requesting everything required.